# Complex SELECT Operation in SQL Server 2012 and later

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

Table schema:

```
CREATE TABLE TRANSACTIONDETAILS
(
    TransNo CHAR(15),
    Serial  INT,
    Project CHAR(3)
)
```

Dataset:

```
+-----------------+--------+---------+
|     TransNo     | Serial | Project |
+-----------------+--------+---------+
| A00000000000001 |      1 |     100 |
| A00000000000001 |      2 |     100 |
| A00000000000002 |      1 |     100 |
| A00000000000002 |      2 |     101 |
| A00000000000003 |      1 |     200 |
| A00000000000003 |      2 |     200 |
| A00000000000003 |      3 |     101 |
| A00000000000004 |      1 |     101 |
| A00000000000004 |      2 |     101 |
| A00000000000005 |      1 |     100 |
| A00000000000005 |      2 |     200 |
+-----------------+--------+---------+
```

I want to select rows those have different project for same TransNo.

Expected output:

```
+-----------------+--------+---------+
|     TransNo     | Serial | Project |
+-----------------+--------+---------+
| A00000000000002 |      1 |     100 |
| A00000000000002 |      2 |     101 |
| A00000000000003 |      1 |     200 |
| A00000000000003 |      2 |     200 |
| A00000000000003 |      3 |     101 |
| A00000000000005 |      1 |     100 |
| A00000000000005 |      2 |     200 |
+-----------------+--------+---------+
```

I am using SQL Server 2012 and later.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use subquery to get the list of `TransNo` that have more than one distinct project and then filter initial list only by results from subquery:

```
SELECT TransNo, Serial, Project
FROM TRANSACTIONDETAILS
WHERE TransNo IN (
    SELECT TransNo
    FROM TRANSACTIONDETAILS
    GROUP BY TransNo
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Project) > 1   -- only select TransNo that have more than 
                                         -- one distinct project
  )
```

Here is [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/86fc8/5/0)

Answer (score 1):

What you'll want to do is get a table with the duplicates.
`SELECT 
  TransNo,
  Project
FROM TRANSACTIONDETAILS
GROUP BY TransNo, Project
HAVING COUNT(1) > 1`

then you'll want to join back to the table. Here's the complete query:
`SELECT
   A.TransNo, A.Serial, A.Project
 FROM TRANSACTIONDETAILS A
 INNER JOIN (
   SELECT 
     TransNo,
     Project
    FROM TRANSACTIONDETAILS
   GROUP BY TransNo, Project
   HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Project) > 1
  ) B
ON A.TransNo = B.TransNo`

Answer (score 1):

```
    with cte
    as
    (
        select row_number() over (partition by TransNo,Project order by   transno) as cnt,*
      from TRANSACTIONDETAILS
    )
select TransNo,
    Serial,
    Project
from cte
where cnt=1
```

try this code